# Operate on all rows of a matrix without loop, octave

Tags: octave, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix A and I want to obtain the following:

```
for i=1:m
  A(i,:) = something which depends on i;
endfor
```

Is there a way to obtain that without the loop?

**Added:** Ok, I've understood I have to be more specific. 
I have two matrices `B` and `C` (all the matrices we are considering have `m` rows). 
I want to record in the `i`-th row of `A` the product of the polynomials written in the `i`-th rows of `B` and `C` (so using the loop I would call the conv function).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this without a for loop as `conv` only accepts vector inputs, but I might be wrong. I can't see a way of using either `bsxfun` or `arrayfun` in conjunction with `conv` and matrix inputs. I might be wrong though... I stand to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very very general question, and not possible to answer with more details. Mainly on what `i` will be involved with. Suppose the following

```
for i = 1:m
  A(i,:) += i;
endfor
```

It could be written with the much more efficient:

```
A .+ (1:m)'
```

Just compare:

```
octave> n = 1000;
octave> A = B = rand (n);
octave> tic; for i = 1:n, B(i,:) += i; endfor; toc
Elapsed time is 0.051 seconds.
octave> tic; C = A.+ (1:n)'; toc
Elapsed time is 0.01 seconds.
octave> isequal (C, B)
ans =  1
```

If you have a very old version of octave, you can instead do `bsxfun (@plus, A, (i:m)')`.

However, if `i` on the right side of the expression will be used for indexing some other variable, then solution would be different. Maybe, the solution is `cumsum`, or some other of `cumfoo` function.

Your question is basically, "how do I vectorize code?", which is a really large subject, without telling us what you're trying to vectorize.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've added the details about what I'm trying to do.